# Extend MDM Solution for Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos, mdm

We have been developig a MDM server which are to support for iOS as well as Mac OS X. So we were able to enroll iOS devices with our server. Now we are head into Mac OS X implementation. According to this (http://training.apple.com/pdf/wp_osx_configuration_profiles_ml.pdf) some attributes are changed in Plist. When we try to enroll a Mac OS X laptop with our server it does the first four steps which are enroll, profile, GetCACaps and GetCACert.Then unexpected error has been occurred in client side. Here is system.log. What would be the reason ?

```
 Mar  7 12:13:21 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
 Mar  7 12:13:21 chamara mdmclient[626]: *** ERROR *** [Agent:503] <:  [MDM_SCEP_Enroll] Calling SCEPGetCACert.  CA Ident: EnrollmentCAInstance -->  <NSOSStatusErrorDomain:-25300>
 Mar  7 12:13:21 chamara mdmclient[626]: *** ERROR *** [Agent:503] ExtractOTAIdentity ( <NSOSStatusErrorDomain:-25300>)
 Mar  7 12:13:21 chamara mdmclient[626]: *** ERROR *** [Agent:503] ProcessOTABootstrapProfileCore ( <NSOSStatusErrorDomain:-25300>)
 Mar  7 12:13:21 chamara WindowServer[95]: _CGXGetWindowOrderingGroup: Operation on a window 0x101 requiring rights 0x5 by caller System Preferences
 Mar  7 12:13:21 chamara  com.apple.preferences.configurationprofiles.remoteservice[625]: *** ERROR ***  [CPInstallerUI:503] Profile installation ( MDM Service  (com.mac.mdm.profile-service)) (<NSOSStatusErrorDomain:-25300> The operation  couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -25300.)
 UserInfo: {
    CallStackSymbols =     (
        "0   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b6ff0a mdmclient + 20234",
        "1   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b9a177 mdmclient + 192887",
        "2   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b7bf97 mdmclient + 69527",
        "3   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b8b9a7 mdmclient + 133543",
        "4   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b7e544 mdmclient + 79172",
        "5   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b8b80d mdmclient + 133133",
        "6   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b88115 mdmclient + 119061",
        "7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa428d _dispatch_client_callout + 8",
        "8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baab3b0 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 39",
        "9   mdmclient                           0x0000000105b88045 mdmclient + 118853",
        "10  mdmclient                           0x0000000105b8848d mdmclient + 119949",
        "11  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff917275cc _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 58",
        "12  libxpc.dylib                        0x00007fff917261df _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2124",
        "13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa7ae2 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 9",
        "14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa839c _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 143",
        "15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa6617 _dispatch_queue_drain + 359",
        "16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa7682 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 154",
        "17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa5f87 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75",
        "18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8baa7177 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40",
        "19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8b273ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314",
        "20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff8b276fb9 start_wqthread + 13"
    );
    IsInternalError = 1;
})
Mar  7 12:13:22 chama
```

Comment: Just a guess, but does your Mac trust the root CA that issued the certificate?

Comment: SSL certificate is signed by Digicert. But  CA and RA which are used in SCEP protocol were self-signed ones.

Comment: @GPrathap Were you able to resolve this error? If yes, can you please share how?

Comment: @user2421978 , nope working with Mac devices just a nightmare :)